# How to convert this cURL request into node request call?

Tags: node.js, http, curl, request

I have tried every way I can think of to format this cURL request into something I can do server side on node and I keep getting back an invalid credentials response. I know the creds are valid so I must come to the conclusion that the code is making the wrong type of request.

cURL request:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.timekit.io/v2/bookings\
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --user : api_key_dfagafrgaegrfareVhROys9V1bUJ1z7
```

my format:

```
var options = {
            url: 'https://api.timekit.io/v2/bookings',
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'user': APP_KEY
            },
            method:'GET'
        };

        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body);
            }
        }

        request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `--user user:password` in your curl command.

When you pass --user  to curl, it sends it to the server as an basic authorization header (with the user:password encoded using base64). You can try this by running it against httpbin.org:

```
curl --request GET --url http://httpbin.org/headers --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --user foo:bar
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Authorization": "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.61.1"
  }
}
```

As you can see, they received the header `"Authorization": "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg=="` where `Zm9vOmJhcg==` is the base64 encode of `foo:bar`